Get count of values based on another table in SQL Server
I have 2 tables, Products & Discounts, where I need to get count of countries where the qty value is less than equal to size.
Here are the two tables:
CREATE TABLE Products 
(
    P_Name VARCHAR(50), 
    Qty INT
);

INSERT INTO Products (P_Name, Qty)
VALUES 
    ('Product A', 9),
    ('Product B', 2);

CREATE TABLE Discounts 
(
    C_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Size INT
);

INSERT INTO Discounts (C_Name, Size) 
VALUES 
    ('USA', 2 ),
    ('Germany', 4),
    ('Brazil', 5),
    ('Russia', 6);


Fiddle

Here is the expected output:
P_Name     Qty  Count
---------------------
Product A   9    4
Product B   2    1

Explanation: for Product A, the Qty is 9, so it's eligible to get discounts in 4 countries, similarly for Product B the Qty should be 1.
Here is what I tried, but I'm unable to get correct output:
SELECT *,
    COUNT (
        CASE 
            WHEN qty <= (SELECT Size FROM Discounts) 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS count
FROM
    Products;


Use a (LEFT) JOIN. You also don't have a GROUP BY when you have an aggregate function.

there isnt any common column between these two table to join

Yes there is: qty and size...

Looks like it's just LEFT JOIN Discounts d ON d.Size <= p.Qty then GROUP BY P_Name the subquery in the SELECT seems unnecessary. Alternatively you can continue using the subquery but then do it like this SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Discount d WHERE d.Size <= p.Qty)

oh silly me, d.Size <= p.Qty with left join was the thing... Thanks guys

maybe you can try something like the one below. I added also order by product but that can be optional:
SELECT 
    P.P_Name,
    P.Qty,
    COUNT(D.C_Name) AS Count
FROM 
    Products AS P
LEFT JOIN 
    Discounts AS D ON P.Qty <= D.Size
GROUP BY 
    P.P_Name, P.Qty;
ORDER BY 
    P.P_Name;


See it work here: https://dbfiddle.uk/Yks4G-iU

SELECT P.P_NAME,P.Qty,X.CNTT
FROM Products AS P
OUTER APPLY
(
   SELECT SUM(A.XCOUNT)AS CNTT FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      CASE 
       WHEN P.Qty>=D.Size THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
     END AS XCOUNT
    FROM Discounts AS D
 )AS A
)X

Based on your sample data could you please try something like above

This is usually either done via a scalar subquery or a group by:
select P_Name, Qty,
    (select count(*) from Discounts d where d.Size <= p.Qty) as "Count"
from Products p;

or
select p.P_Name, min(p.Qty) as Qty, count(d.Size) as "Count"
from Products p left outer join Discounts d -- handles possibility of zero matches
    on d.Size <= p.Qty
group by p.P_Name;

